# Facing Error while applying excel formula in Macro

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have the below type of values in column J in excel

```
<a href="http://twitter.com" rel="nofollow">Twitter Web Client</a>
```

and, I have used this formula

```
=RIGHT(LEFT(J2,LEN(J2)-4),LEN(LEFT(J2,LEN(J2)-4))FIND(">",LEFT(J2,LEN(J2)-4),2))
```

to get this value "Twitter Web Client.

When I tried to apply Macro for this using below code in not getting value. Also help me in code by applying formula in the entire range of 'Q' column referencing the 'J' column

```
Sub Enter_Formula()

    Range("Q2").Formula = "=RIGHT(LEFT(J2,LEN(J2)-4),LEN(LEFT(J2,LEN(J2)-4))-FIND(" > ",LEFT(J2,LEN(J2)-4),2))"

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to double the quotes within the formula. This has been asked many times before I think.

Comment: I have double quoted within formula , I'm getting TRUE not the exact value  i.e. Twitter Web Client

Comment: Really? It's not in the code you posted. It should read: `"=RIGHT(LEFT(J2,LEN(J2)-4),LEN(LEFT(J2,LEN(J2)-4))-FIND("" > "",LEFT(J2,LEN(J2)-4),2))"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this

```
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
MsgBox LastRow 'This would give the User range value to be used to enter the formulaa in all the rows
Range("Q2:Q" & LastRow).Formula = "=LEFT(RIGHT(RC[-7],LEN(RC[-7])-FIND("">"",RC[-7],2)),LEN(RIGHT(RC[-7],LEN(RC[-7])-FIND("">"",RC[-7],2)))-4)"
```

The result set would be "Twitter Web Client" text.